# GET and POST requests in gdscript

Tags: godot

How do I perform get and post requests from Gdscript in Godot?
I am trying to get a map API and use it in the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As someone else said, check out the [HTTPClient class](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/http_client_class.html).

It's nonblocking, so you'll need to check for when it's finished.

A barebones example with no error checking would be the following:

```
var http = HTTPClient.new()
http.connect("www.myapi.net",80)
var headers=[
    "User-Agent: Pirulo/1.0 (Godot)",
    "Accept: */*"
]
http.request(HTTPClient.METHOD_GET,"/myendpoint",headers)
if (http.has_response()):
    #read through the chunks...
```

Really, this is just pseudo-code. The docs have a really complete code example. http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/http_client_class.html